# Could not get the properties of a generic type by using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am simplyfing the question here, so the example could not make any sence for the real world.

```
public class BusinessEntity<T>
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class Customer : BusinessEntity<Customer>
{

    public string FirstName { get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set;}
}
```

When I try to get Customer class properties by reflection, I could not get the properties of the generic base class. How to get Id from the BusinessEntity ?

```
Type type = typeof(Customer);

PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(); 
// Just FirstName and LastName listed here. I also need Id here
```

Comment: Just tested this, my returned properties array always has 3 entries (VS2012, tried multiple target frameworks).

Comment: "How to get Id from the BusinessEntity ?" go and wash your eyes? :p

Comment: Here's the trick: when you simplify code for a question, *check it still shows the problem*. If it does **not** show the problem, then look at what is different between the real code and the simplified code, and then you've *answered it yourself*.

Comment: I am laughing myself now (: Thanks all. Really thanks also for your kind advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, that definitely returns all 3 properties. Check that in your *real* code, whether `Id` is `internal` / `protected` / etc (i.e. non-public). If it is, you'll need to pass in `BindingFlags`, for example:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

(the default is public + instance + static)

Also check that it isn't a **field** in your actual code; if it is:

```
public int Id;
```

then it is a field, and you should <s>use `GetFields`</s> ***make `Id` a property*** ;p

Comment: Actually it has been declared as field as you mention. My bad (: Thanks

Comment: +1 for i learnt something new from your comments above on my answer

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the base properties you will have to use the BaseType property of the Type

```
PropertyInfo[] baseProperties = typeof(Customer).BaseType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Customer).GetProperties();
```

Comment: The thing is... it isn't true. You get the inherited properties by default. In fact, you have to pass in extra flags to *not* get them.

Comment: @MarcGravell yes I agree, but this is one the way to get a types base properties

Comment: Well, kind-of; if you were doing that, you'd probably want to be specifying `DeclaredOnly`, otherwise you're doubling up

Answer (score 1):

What is the issue, your code is perfectly fine and returning the correct properties

```
Type type = typeof(Customer);
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(); 
foreach(var prop in properties)
{ Console.WriteLine(prop) }
```

Result

```
System.String FirstName 
System.String LastName 
Int32 Id
```